# CSS Style Issue with Content Slider Pointer

Tags: css

I am trying to modify a JQuery Content Slider that Im currently using to have the Thumb pics appear at the bottom instead of appearing at the side:

Here is the current Content Slider that has the Thumb Pics on the side:
http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/6WXkM/
[image]

This is my implementation where I have moved the Thumb Pics at the bottom:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/QaLg2/

As you can see the problem is that my Arrow Pointer has dissappeared.  Does anyone know why is this occurring?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's not working the way you wanted it to be, is simply because the first image of the bottom bar is placed in a separate parent element, while the rest of the images in the bottom bar is placed under an second parent element.

I have made some changes to your file. Try checking it out here again: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5tXgQ/3/

On a side note, I don't recommend wrapping the `<a>` in an unnecessary `<div>` element. They could be floated without the help of a wrapper `<div>`.

Comment: @teddyrised the change you made actually eliminated the pointer, do you know why?   http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5tXgQ/3/

Comment: Sorry, accidentally set the wrapping container to hide overflowing content. Now I've added a negative top margin and a positive top padding to counter that. I hope it's working now - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5tXgQ/5/

Comment: @teddyrised I like your implementation.  I revised my Issue though, because Im basically trying to replicate as much style as possible to another Slider that Im already using.  If you check it out you can see that the Thumb that is selected changes its background color to grey.  Which is sort-of what I already have.  But for this Im having an issue with the pointer.

Comment: My hack allows the pointer to be displayed and the floated children elements to be cleared properly (without the need to insert those `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` elements that carry no semantic meaning.

However, the negative margin + positive padding combo also means it will overlap with the bottom of the content slider a little.

Comment: I baselined this: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/5tXgQ/6/  and now IM trying to add they gray background that is missing for the Thumb that is selected.  Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: Sorry Paul, but what is your question?

Comment: In this Example you can see that for the Thumb Selected, the background of the Thumb becomes grey: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/6WXkM/ Since I already have that in the Website Im trying to replicate that style for the new Slider that you just helped me with here http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/5tXgQ/

Comment: The background of the thumb turns grey too because you have assigned `background: grey` for the whole `<div class="active-thumb">` container. The `<div>` has the arrow as the background-image, so the arrow will be superimposed against a grey background, too.

If you don't want that to happen, perhaps you should remove the background-color for the whole `<div>`. Instead, add padding to the `<img>` within the `<div>` and assign background-color to it instead. That should help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/5tXgQ/   I really appreciate it, I think now it is very close!

Comment: Removed the `.nav-thumb` property alltogether, since we're already selecting it using `#movers-row div img`. It contains a `margin-right: 6px` property, which is messing with the centering of the background arrow image.

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5tXgQ/13/

Comment: I figured out the space between the bottom of the arrow and the grey background: by reducing the cross-link top padding, also I attempted to remove the nav-thumb class from the Thumb images and it behaved strange

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you modify its style="border-color: black; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"